# How to only grep and sorted value from other column

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I have an input file1.txt like below:

file1.txt :

```
test 1 Vertical                                564N,
test 2 Vertical                                551N,
test 3 Hydrophone                              127N, 223D, 344D,
test 4 Hydrophone                              350D,
test 6 Hydrophone                              407D,
```

How can I grab only 4th column matched value and then sorted into following?

```
Output :
N   D 
564 223 
551 344
127 350
    407
```

Comment: Are the columns separated with tabs? If not, it might be tricky.

Comment: Yes, it is separated with tabs

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNU awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=",? *"                 #
    OFS="\t"                  # output fields separated by tabs
}
{
    for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)        # process fields 4 and above
        if($i~/N/)            # hash n and d accordingly
            n[++j]=$i
        else if($i~/D/)
            d[++k]=$i
}
END {
    n[j=0]="N"                # headers 
    d[k=0]="D"
    while(n[j]!=""||d[k]!="") # output them untile they run out
        print substr(n[j],1,length(n[j++]-1)),substr(d[k],1,length(d[k++]-1))
}' file
```

Output:

```
N      D
564    223
551    344
127    350
       407
```

Answer (score 1):

And a perl version with output that's formatted like yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw/zip/;

my %nums;
while (<>) {
  my @f = split /\s+/;
  for my $nd (@f[3..$#f]) {
    if ($nd =~ /^(\d+)([ND])/) {
      push @{$nums{$2}}, $1;
    }
  }
}
print "N   D\n";
my @pairs = zip @{$nums{N}}, @{$nums{D}};
while (@pairs) {
  my ($n, $d) = (shift @pairs, shift @pairs);
  printf "%-3s %-3s\n", $n//"", $d//"";
}
```

Edit: After some golfing and playing around:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw/zip6/;
my %nums = (N => [ "N" ], D => [ "D" ]);
while (<>) {
  my @f = split /\s+/;
  for my $nd (@f[3..$#f]) {
    push @{$nums{$2}}, $1 if $nd =~ m/^(\d+)([ND])/;
  }
}
printf "%-3s %-3s\n", $_->[0]//"", $_->[1]//"" for zip6 @{$nums{N}}, @{$nums{D}};
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, this doesn't work, because it can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at test2.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test2.pl line 4

Comment: @Amz You might have to install the module. I can't remember if it's core or not.

Comment: @Shawn: Only `List::Util` is core, but is has been expanded a lot in recent years.

Comment: @Borodin Expanded, maybe, but still nothing like `zip` in it. I do see a `pairmap` function I never noticed before even though it looks to have been around for ages, though, which would have been useful. Have to remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution

The input file is read and the first three columns discarded from each line. What remains is searched for fields that look like `999N` or `999D` and they are split into a hash of arrays with `N` and `D` as its keys

After sorting the arrays, they are displayed as columns beneath appropriate headers

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use List::Util 'max';

open my $fh, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;

my %data;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my @fields = split ' ', $_, 4;
    push @{ $data{$2} }, $1 while $fields[3] =~ /(\d+)([ND])/g;
}

$_ = [ sort { $a <=> $b } @$_ ] for values %data;

my $last = max map $#$_, values %data;

my $fmt = "%-3s %-3s\n";
printf $fmt, qw/ N D /;
for my $i ( 0 .. $last ) {
    printf $fmt, map { $_->[$i] // '' } @data{qw/ N D /};
}
```

#### output

```
N   D  
127 223
551 344
564 350
    407
```

Comment: This works great, plus I can re-use these script to manipulate different parameters for different tasks. Thanks again Borodin.

Comment: @Amz: I've written some annotations. What do you want to know?

Answer (score -1):

This should help.

#### Python code

```
from itertools import izip_longest
#Python3
#from itertools import zip_longest

N = []
D = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:                   #Iterate Each line
        val = line.split()[3:]            #Get Required value using slicing
        for i in val:
            if i.endswith("N,"):
                N.append(int(i.rstrip("N,")))
            else:
                D.append(int(i.rstrip("D,")))

for i in izip_longest(sorted(N, reverse=True), sorted(D), fillvalue=""):    #Sort and iterate. 
    print(i)
```

#### Output

```
564, 223
551, 344
127, 350
'', 407
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your answer, I will try it on my workspace.

Comment: There is no mention of Python in the question tags

Comment: @Borodin...OP has edited the question.